# How do I force SqlCommand to not encode parameters as unicode/nvarchar?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database table with 81 million records that are used to tie a specific URL with a customer that requested the url to be generated.  In order for querying urls from this table to be somewhat reasonable I made the url field a `varchar(500)` (max url length we've seen is 410).

When I run the following query in SSMS, I get results instantaneously:

```
select CustomerId, UserId, Requested from LogURL where LogData = '<url>'
```

I then coded a method in C# to do this query for me to process log files:

```
    public UrlInformation GetInfoForUrl(string url)
    {
        const string query = "select top 1 CustomerId, UserId, Requested from LogURL where LogData = @url";

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                DbType = DbType.AnsiString,
                ParameterName = "url",
                Value = url
            });

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                UrlInformation info = null;

                // Sometimes there are multiple results, just take the first
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    var customerId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    var userId = reader.GetInt32(1);
                    var date = reader.GetDateTime(2);

                    info = new UrlInformation
                    {
                        CustomerId = customerId,
                        UserId = userId,
                        RequestedDate = date
                    };
                }

                return info;
            }
        }
```

(Note that this class creates and opens the sql connection in the constructor, and disposes it in Dispose(), so the same connection should be re-used).

When this code runs, `command.ExecuteReader()` takes 3-5 seconds each (measured via the `StopWatch` class).  Opening up the sql profiler I see the actual query getting executed is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select top 1 CustomerId, UserId, Requested from LogURL where LogData = @url',N'@url nvarchar(346)',@url=N'<url>'
```

Since it's converting the url to a `nvarchar` it's not utilizing my `varchar()` references and seems to be doing a full table scan.

How can I get the C# code to consider the url as a varchar instead of nvarchar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using **SqlParameter** might as well be using **SqlDbType** instead of **DbType**.  If you do that, then you can use **SqlDbType.VarChar** instead of **DbType.Ansi**.

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
{
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
    ParameterName = "url",
    Value = url
});
```

Also, from MSDN, the **DbType** parameter **DbType** gets or sets the **SqlDbType** of the parameter by overriding the base **DbType** property.

Comment: Perfect, I haven't had to types via sql parameters before so I didn't notice the SqlDbType.  Doing this worked!  I'll accept it once SO lets me.

Comment: Please do confirm that it works, as I am curious.  According to the documentation, AnsiString is the non Unicode type, so either there is a bug interpreting the enum value, or there is a bug later, and my answer might not work.

Comment: It does work, it made my ExecuteReader() calls go from 4500ms to 0.03ms (according to the StopWatch.ElaspedMillisends)

Comment: As a note, I had to use the named parameters as the example above. Setting them in the constructor with the dbtype and size did not work, it set my parameter as "default" and not the actual value.